# Rails, how to store a birthday string "06/20/1980" in a timestamp field in the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm getting a bday from FB as a string like so: 06/20/1980

I want to save this in my db User.birthday which is a timestamp. But it's failing.

How can I save this? Thanks

Comment: Aim for the [data type `date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rubys `Date` class can parse arbitrary formats.

```
Date.strptime("06/20/1980", "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: That is returning invalid date

Comment: @AnApprentice: I find that highly unlikely unless you forgot to include the format string in your `Date.strptime` call.